# C - Reading from file - Why is it printing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to display a matrix (walls are surrounded by **#** and inside is surrounded by space) 
I am able to populate it by default

**Goal** is to read a matrix from a file, and store it in the pointer (map)

**If insert_from_file is commented out you will see it is populating properly**

I am allocating memory and then reallocating memory for the new **ROWS & COLUMNS**

**Link to file:**
http://www.filedropper.com/map1_18

But it still doesn't print the contents of the file right.

```
Actual File: 

########################
#      #          #    #
#                 #  * #
#      #    M     #    #
#      #               #
### ####################
#     # M         #    #
# #####  #######  #    #
# #      #             #
# # ###  #  M       @  #
#   #    #             #
########################

The way it is printing:

########################
�#      #          #    
#�#                 #  *
 #�#      #    M     #  
  #�#      #            
   #�### ###############
#####�#     # M         
#    #�# #####  ####### 
 #    #�# #      #      
       #�# # ###  #  M  
     @  #�#   #    #    
         #�#############
```

Below is the code I could make as **Minimal** as possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char get(unsigned x, unsigned y);
void put(unsigned x, unsigned y, char v);
void print_map();
void populate_map();
void set_rows_cols(char const *file_name);
void insert_from_file(char const *file_name);

size_t ROWS = 10;
size_t COLS = 10;
char *map;

char get(unsigned x, unsigned y) { return *(map + (y * COLS) + x); }
void put(unsigned x, unsigned y, char v) { *(map + (y*COLS) + x) = v;}
void print_map() {
    for(int x = 0; x < ROWS; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < COLS; y++) {
            putchar(get(y, x));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
void populate_map() {
    for(int x = 0; x < ROWS; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < COLS; y++) {
            if (x == 0 || x == ROWS - 1 || y == 0 || y == COLS -1) {
                put(y, x, '#');
            } else {
                put(y, x, ' ');
            }
        }
    }
}

void set_rows_cols(char const *file_name) {
    free(map);
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    char mychar;
    int tempRows = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while((mychar = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (mychar == '\n') {
            tempRows++;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    COLS = (counter / tempRows);
    ROWS = tempRows;
    map = NULL;
    map = calloc(1000, sizeof(ROWS*COLS));
    fclose(file);
    printf("newRows: %zu\n", ROWS);
    printf("newCOLS: %zu\n", COLS);
}

void insert_from_file(char const *file_name) {
    set_rows_cols(file_name);
    FILE *myfile = fopen(file_name, "r");
    int tempR = 0;
    int tempC = 0;
    char mychar;

    for(tempR = 0; tempR < ROWS; tempR++) {
        for(tempC = 0; tempC < COLS; tempC++) {
            mychar = getc(myfile);
            if(mychar != EOF) {
                if (mychar != '\n') {
                    put(tempC, tempR, mychar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(myfile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    map = malloc(sizeof(ROWS * COLS));
    populate_map();
    insert_from_file("map1.txt");
    print_map();
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Do not add unrelated tags! And there is no 2D array/matrix in your code! (Would be good to use one, though)

Comment: `map = malloc(sizeof(ROWS * COLS));` is totally wrong.

Comment: Do you terminate the output strings?

Comment: @PaulR - Would you be able to explain what is wrong with it? I am new to C, please bare with me.

Comment: `sizeof` is for getting the sizes of certain types or variables. If you want to allocate room for `ROWS * COLS` bytes (which should be enough for `ROWS * COLS` characters), then you should `malloc(ROWS * COLS)`.

Comment: I think we need to know how you wrote the matrix to the file in the first place. It looks like you have phantom null characters after each newline.

Comment: They are files found online -

Comment: Could we get links to examine their contents?

Comment: @Purag - Link added above!

Comment: You define get(x,y) but call it get(y,x).  Same for put.

Comment: Instead of `map = malloc(sizeof(ROWS * COLS));` --> `map = malloc(sizeof *map * ROWS * COLS);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some issues with undefined behavior.  You're not allocating the proper amount of space for `map`:

```
map = malloc(sizeof(ROWS * COLS));
```

The `sizeof` operator gives you the size of the given datatype in bytes.  In this case, the expression `ROWS * COLS` is of type `size_t` (since that is the type of both operands) and it evaluates to 8 on my system.  Get rid of the `sizeof`:

```
map = malloc(sizeof(ROWS * COLS));
```

Similarly here:

```
map = calloc(1000, sizeof(ROWS*COLS));
```

This actually allocates space for 1000 8-byte elements.  You can just use the same `malloc` command that you did before.

Now for the output issue, which is here:

```
for(tempR = 0; tempR < ROWS; tempR++) {
    for(tempC = 0; tempC < COLS; tempC++) {
        mychar = getc(myfile);
        if(mychar != EOF) {
            if (mychar != '\n') {
                put(tempC, tempR, mychar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you're reading in a newline character, you still increment `tempC` and `tempR`.  That's why the output is skewed.

Just do the read in the inner loop, and do one extra read on the outer loop to get the newline:

```
for(tempR = 0; tempR < ROWS; tempR++) {
    for(tempC = 0; tempC < COLS; tempC++) {
        mychar = getc(myfile);
        put(tempC, tempR, mychar);
    }
    mychar = getc(myfile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This has fixed the issue I was having! +1